# Will the 2017 15" MBP touchbar work with a Dell U3417W?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I need to purchase a new MBP for my boss. He wants all of the bells and whistles and he wants a docking station at home with a nice screen. He likes the Dell U3417W but I'm not clear whether there is a way to have it work with the new MBP.

I'm generally a PC guy so I don't feel qualified to answer the question myself. I found a [short discussion](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3529/t/20026701) about it. The Dell "liaison" recommended the user pose the question on the Apple forum. When I search the Apple forum for U3417w I don't see anything posted.

Can anyone tell me if this will work and if not, why?

Comment: I have done a quick search on reddit, and to no avail, it says that the display should work with either HDMI or mDP. Personally, (in that price range) is the fully apple endorsed [LG UltraFine 5K](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKN62/lg-ultrafine-5k-display?fnode=4c) and [LG UltraFine 4K](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HKMY2VC/A/lg-ultrafine-4k-display?fnode=8a) monitor lineup, which is almost guaranteed to produce optimal (non-problematic) results. — Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't it work?  It's just a monitor and the MacBook Pro is an Intel based computer.

The [MacBook Pro](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/) will support

- Up to two displays with 5120-by-2880 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors
- Up to four displays with 4096-by-2304 resolution at 60Hz at millions of colors
- Up to four displays with 3840-by-2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colors

The [Dell](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-u3417w-monitor/pd) will support a maximum resolution of 3440 x 1440 at 60 Hz

Just go from DisplayPort to DisplayPort with the proper [USB-C to DisplayPort cable](http://radnex.us/Cable-Matters-USB-C-Display-Port-Cable-4K) (I prefer to avoid conversion to HDMI) and it should work just fine.

For the record, the only monitors I use are Dells.  I have sizes ranging from very old 19" DVI models to 30" Dual Link DVI models and everything in between.  I use a 24" UltraSharp at my remote office with both a MacBook Pro and a Surface Pro and it performs beautifully with zero issues.